# Why does lines() not draw confidence interval

Tags: r, plot, regression, linear-regression, lm

I try to plot confidence interval of a linear regression line, but the `lines()` function doesn't work. What should I do to fix this issue?

```
Jahr<-Jahr[2:26]
Menge<-Menge[1:25]
plot(Jahr,Menge,xlim=c(1991,2016),ylim=c(25000000,550000000))

coef<-lm(Menge~Jahr)
abline(coef,col="blue")

PredictPoint<-predict(coef,data.frame(Jahr=c(2016)),interval="none")
points.default(x=2016,y=PredictPoint,type="p",col="red",pch=1)
conf<-predict(coef, data.frame(Jahr=c(2016)), interval = "confidence")
lines(data.frame(Jahr=c(2016)),conf[,2],col="red")
lines(data.frame(Jahr=c(2016)),conf[,3],col="red")
```

Comment: Yes :-) but thanks for the linkes. My Problem is, that I have no success to plot it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you only predict one data point at year 2016:

```
conf<-predict(coef, data.frame(Jahr=c(2016)), interval = "confidence")
```

how could `lines` line up a single point to produce a line? By default, `lines` has `type = "l"`. If you set `type = "b"`, it will display **b**oth points and lines. In case you only have one datum, it will display points.

Another problem is that you pass a data frame rather than a vector to the first argument of `lines`.

Altogether, do:

```
lines(2016, conf[,2], col="red", type = "b")
lines(2016, conf[,3], col="red", type = "b")
```

---

If you only want confidence interval for this single point, maybe this is better:

```
segments(2016, conf[,2], 2016, conf[,3], lty = 2, col = "red")
```

Comment: Thnks a lot.  Your solution gives me only two point, but I need two lines